# Why does nonce have to increment by one? Wouldn't it be sufficient to require unique nonces?

Tags: transactions, nonce, replay-attack

For replay protection, it would be sufficient to require a unique nonce for every transaction from the same address. More precisely, it would be sufficient to consider a new transaction T from an address A with a nonce N inadmissible in the ledger if another transaction T' from A with nonce N already occurs in the ledger.

But Ethereum is more strict. Roughly speaking, it considers a transaction T from A with nonce N inadmissible in the ledger if N is not equal to M+1, where M is the nonce of the last transaction from A in the ledger.

Why is that? Why is Ethereum more strict than it needs to be?

I can think of two reasons:

1. The stricter approach is more efficient (in space and time) to check.
2. The stricter approach gives users a way to control the execution order of their transactions.

Are there other reasons?

Comment: I'd love to see an authoritative answer to your question, but for what it's worth, the two reasons you listed are what I personally believe led to this decision.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that both of your reasons are correct. I'm not aware of other reasons, although I know some people find managing nonces frustrating. In the future it appears as if [the use of nonces may change](https://ethresear.ch/t/tradeoffs-in-account-abstraction-proposals/263), I've even heard suggestions of nonces being completely removed with account abstraction.